# check log4j vulnerability for Elasticsearch

Tags: java, log4j2

how to confirm if elasticsearch version is exposed to log4j vulnerability? My elasticsearch version is 6.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 version 2.17 which solves the vulnerability [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) is included in Elasticserach version 6.8.22 or in 7.16.2 as you can read on respective release-notes:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/release-notes-7.16.2.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-notes-6.8.22.html

> Upgrade to log4j 2.17.0 #81902

The specific upgrade for log4j2 version in Elasticsearch [is on #81902](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/81902)

Comment: hi @albciff, thank you for your quick response.. I would probably go with 6.8.22 for now, let me check if my application is working with the same.

Comment: hi @albciff, I checked out my organization repos and found v6.8.22 available and managed to upgrade without issues. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @PankajK, I'm glad that this answer help you :)